# Order each group by one column and get top elements depending on each group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe with the following columns:

| month | userID | probability | top_users_that_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | A | 5.231 | 3 |
| 9 | B | 0.963 | 3 |
| 9 | E | 7.445 | 3 |
| 9 | D | 9.343 | 3 |
| 9 | C | 3.231 | 3 |
| 10 | X | 0.963 | 1 |
| 10 | B | 7.445 | 1 |
| 10 | A | 2.343 | 1 |
| 13 | Y | 1.963 | 2 |
| 13 | B | 9.445 | 2 |
| 13 | D | 0.343 | 2 |

I would like to create a flag column, which has values 1 or 0, depending on if the userID was among the top_users (according to their `probability` column) for each month. Note that the number of top users in each month is indicated by the `top_users_that_month` column.

The desired output would be the following:

| month | userID | probability | top_users_that_month | flag_among_top_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | A | 5.231 | 3 | 1 |
| 9 | B | 0.963 | 3 | 0 |
| 9 | E | 7.445 | 3 | 1 |
| 9 | D | 9.343 | 3 | 1 |
| 9 | C | 3.231 | 3 | 0 |
| 10 | X | 0.963 | 1 | 0 |
| 10 | B | 7.445 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | A | 2.343 | 1 | 0 |
| 11 | Y | 1.963 | 2 | 1 |
| 11 | B | 9.445 | 2 | 1 |
| 11 | D | 0.343 | 2 | 0 |

I have tried to create the column using `groupby` and `apply` but didn't get the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of users to be marked differ for each group, the easiest approach would be to use a custom function using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).

For example:

```
def get_top_users(df):
    top_users = df['top_users_that_month'].iloc[0]
    idx = df.sort_values('probability', ascending=False).head(top_users).index
    df['flag_among_top_users'] = 0
    df.loc[idx, 'flag_among_top_users'] = 1
    return df
    
df.groupby('month').apply(get_top_users)
```

Result:

```
    month userID  probability  top_users_that_month  flag_among_top_users
0       9      A        5.231                     3                     1
1       9      B        0.963                     3                     0
2       9      E        7.445                     3                     1
3       9      D        9.343                     3                     1
4       9      C        3.231                     3                     0
5      10      X        0.963                     1                     0
6      10      B        7.445                     1                     1
7      10      A        2.343                     1                     0
8      13      Y        1.963                     2                     1
9      13      B        9.445                     2                     1
10     13      D        0.343                     2                     0
```

It is also possible to use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) instead of sorting inside `get_top_users`, but there could be issues if there are two identical `probability` values.

Comment: Thank you very much! That' s the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @JavierMonsalve: Happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
treshold = 5
df['flag_among_top_users'] = (df['probability'] > treshold).astype(int)
```

Output:

|  | month | userID | probability | top_users_that_month | flag_among_top_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9 | A | 5.231 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 9 | B | 0.963 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 9 | E | 7.445 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 9 | D | 9.343 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 9 | C | 3.231 | 3 | 0 |
| 5 | 10 | X | 0.963 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 10 | B | 7.445 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 10 | A | 2.343 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 13 | Y | 1.963 | 2 | 0 |
| 9 | 13 | B | 9.445 | 2 | 1 |
| 10 | 13 | D | 0.343 | 2 | 0 |